# Insertar datos de JavaScript en HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando meter en el `HTML` de una página unos valores de variables. Lo estoy haciendo modificando el contenido de unos `div` y usando el `innerHTML` .

Pero el problema es que si los insertan no duran, es como que aparecen un instante y desaparecen.

```js
class Productosalimenticios {
  constructor(codigo, nombre, precio) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
  }
  imprimedatos() {
    return (
      "el producto" +
      this.nombre +
      "con el codigo" +
      this.codigo +
      "con un precio" +
      this.precio
    );
  }
}

function Create_products() {
  var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;

  var producto1 = new Productosalimenticios(codigo, nombre, precio);

  codigo = document.getElementById("codigo2").value;
  nombre = document.getElementById("nombre2").value;
  precio = document.getElementById("precio2").value;

  var producto2 = new Productosalimenticios(codigo, nombre, precio);

  codigo = document.getElementById("codigo3").value;
  nombre = document.getElementById("nombre3").value;
  precio = document.getElementById("precio3").value;

  var producto3 = new Productosalimenticios(codigo, nombre, precio);

  var productos = [producto1, producto2, producto3];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById("salida" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = productos[
      i
    ].imprimedatos();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="salida1" id="salida1"></div>
<div class="salida2" id="salida2"></div>
<div class="salida3" id="salida3"></div>
```

Comment: Puedes añadir de donde viene productos y la función imprimedatos();

Comment: ya lo tienes implementado en la pregunta

Comment: ¿Acaso ***productos*** es un `Array`?

Comment: si es un array   `var producto3 = new Productosalimenticios(codigo,nombre,precio);`

Comment: el caso es que los muestra en el documento html pero dura 1 milisegundo.

Comment: Claro, eso no lo había leído. Disculpa

Comment: he estado investigado pero no comprendo porque a mi solo me dura un segundo porque en W3C he visto el mismo codigo y  dura para siempre. como si se crease el elemento desde el **html**

Comment: Hay algo más que está pasando allí. Creo que vas a tener que subir tu código completo o al menos algo más para poder ayudarte, ya que tal como lo has subido funciona a las mil maravillas. No se me ocurre que puede estar pasando. A menos que sea problema específico de tu navegador o algo por el estilo.

Comment: acabo de añadir todo el codigo del javascript

Comment: Tu código, tal y como lo tienes, funciona bien. ¿No tienes más código que pueda estar sobreescribiendo tus divs?

Comment: no no tengo mas codigo ya solo queda el HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba este código, me funciono espero te sea util

```
class Productosalimenticios {
  constructor(codigo, nombre, precio) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
  }

  imprimedatos() {
    return 'el producto ' + this.nombre + ' con el codigo ' + this.codigo + ' con un precio ' + this.precio;
  }
}

function producto(codigo, nombre, precio) {
  function obtValor(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
  }

  var codigo = obtValor(codigo);
  var nombre = obtValor(nombre);
  var precio = obtValor(precio);
  return new Productosalimenticios(codigo, nombre, precio);
}

function Create_products() {
  var producto1 = producto("codigo", "nombre", "precio");
  var producto2 = producto("codigo2", "nombre2", "precio2");
  var producto3 = producto("codigo3", "nombre3", "precio3");

  var productos = [producto1, producto2, producto3];

  for(var i = 0; i < productos.length; i ++) {
    document.getElementById('salida'+(i+1)).innerHTML = productos[i].imprimedatos();
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor siempre considera explicar el código de tus respuestas, pues solo poner un fragmento de código sin más contexto se considera de baja calidad

Comment: buenas muchas gracias por el comentario, pero la he provado y no funciona. he porvado en diferentes navegadores como (safari, google chrome, firefox) y en todos pasa exactamente lo mismo dura una milesima de segundo. lo unico que se me ocurre es probar en un sistema que no sea MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

he encontrado el error pero quisiera una explicacion o que creeis vosotros.

la solucion consta de llamar en el HTML en vez de con un input de tipo submit como lo tenia es cambiarlo por un button.

```
  <form class="formulario">
      <h1>producto 1</h1>
          Codigo: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="Codigo del producto">
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="nombre">
          precio: <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="precio">
      <h1>  producto 2</h1>
          Codigo: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo2" value="Codigo del producto">
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre2" value="nombre">
          precio: <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio2" value="precio">
      <h1>  producto 2 </h1>
          Codigo: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo3" value="Codigo del producto">
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre3" value="nombre">
          precio: <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio3" value="precio">
          <input type="submit"  value="enviar" onclick="Create_products()">
    </form>
```

lo he cambiado a esto

```
        <form class="formulario">
      <h1>producto 1</h1>
          Codigo: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="Codigo del producto">
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="nombre">
          precio: <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="precio">
      <h1>  producto 2</h1>
          Codigo: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo2" value="Codigo del producto">
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre2" value="nombre">
          precio: <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio2" value="precio">
      <h1>  producto 2 </h1>
          Codigo: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo3" value="Codigo del producto">
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre3" value="nombre">
          precio: <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio3" value="precio">

    </form>
  <button onclick="Create_products()">enviar</button>
```

a si he tenido un resultado correcto pero no entiendo porque. Supongo que el sumbit va mas relacionado con el envio del formulario y durara lo que dura la ejecucion del mismo. Y el input pues es mas como para ejecutar algo. vamos que aun asi no lo tengo muy claro.

Comment: Estimado @andres ribeiro, el boton submit envia el formulario al servidor para ser procesado y te devuelve una respuesta que este caso la misma pagina, pero antes de que ocurra todo este se ejecuta el evento onclick que despliega los valores lo cual hace bien pero dura apenas unos segundos porque el submit treae nuevamente la pagina refrescando su contenido.

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicacion ahora lo entiendo. muchas gracias